# What package is Windows.System.Launcher in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am looking to use Windows.System.Launcher in a Windows Form application.  I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 on a Windows 7 machine and the application is .Net 4.5

I can't seem to find what reference to add.  (What package) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Windows.System.Launcher` [is a](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher) Windows Store App API that is only available on Windows 8.

You should call `Process.Start(url)`.

Comment: Thank you, I am actually developing an application for Windows 8.1 on a Windows 7 machine.  I will install Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 on my Windows 8.1 machine and develop there.

Comment: Do you know what reference I need on the Windows 8.1 machine?

Comment: You cannot develop Windows Store apps on Windows 7.  If you create a Windows Store App on a Windows 8+ machine, the reference will be there automatically.  (All WinRT APIs come from a single fake assembly called `Windows`)

Comment: Are you looking for http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

Windows.System.Launcher is a Windows Store app only feature, as can bee seen in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.ASPx):

> Minimum supported client Windows 8 [Windows Store apps only]
>
> Minimum supported server Windows Server 2012 [Windows Store apps only]